# what is the best way to go back to the beginning of a script?

Tags: bash, recursion

I have a script with several inputs, the script eventually initiates a download, once the download is complete i would like to do prompt the user to start the process over if they want to download something else.

```
while true;do
    read -p "Is this correct? (yes/no/abort) " yno
    case $yno in
        [Yy]*) break;;
        [Nn]*) echo "Lets Start Over" 'restart script code goes here';;
        [Aa]*) exit 0;;
            *) echo "Try again";;

    esac
done

echo
echo "Starting $build download for $opt1 from Jenkins"
echo

while true;do
    read -p "Do you want to download something else? " yesno
    case $yesno in
        [Yy]* ) 'restart script code goes here';;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Try Again "
    esac
done
```

Comment: You could use `exec $0` to replace the current invocation with a new one, starting at the top (and without using a new process, which has some advantages).  Alternatively, use `redo=yes; while [ "$redo" = "yes" ]; do ...your current code...; done`, where you'd modify the code to set `redo=no` if the user doesn't want another try.  Between the two, the loop is more conventional.

Comment: This is not really related to shell scripting, you need to learn the basics about conditional statements and loops before you start to implement them. I suggest to create a program flowchart first. (using a pencil)

Answer (score 3):

If you design your shell script with shell functions, repeating a chunk of code gets much easier:

```
main() {
    while true; do
        next
        if ! validate_opt 'Do you want to download something else?'; then
            break
        fi
    done
}
validate_opt() {
    local PS3="$1 (Press ctrl-c to exit) "
    local choice
    select choice in yes no; do
        # This can be written more tersely,
        # but for clarity...
        case $choice in
            yes) return 0;;
             no) return 1;;
        esac
    done
}
do_download() {
    echo
    echo "Starting $build download for $opt1 from Jenkins"
    echo
    fetch "$1" # or whatever
}
next() {
    if validate_opt 'Is this correct?'; then
        do_download "$opt"
    else
        echo "Let's start over"
    fi
}
main
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function stage1 {
while true;do
    read -p "Is this correct? (yes/no/abort) " yno
    case $yno in
        [Yy]*) stage2;;
        [Nn]*) continue;;
        [Aa]*) exit 0;;
            *) echo "Try again";;

    esac
done
}

function stage2 {
echo
echo "Starting $build download for $opt1 from Jenkins"
echo

while true;do
    read -p "Do you want to download something else? " yesno
    case $yesno in
        [Yy]* ) stage1;;
        [Nn]* ) exit 0;;
        * ) echo "Try Again ";;
    esac
done

}
stage1
```

You can do this using functions

The first function is stage 1 and the second stage2
After listing all the functions, at the bottom of the file we call stage1.
when the function stage1 executes and `$yno= Y* or y*` , it will skip to the stage2 function, vice versa when we in stage2

Comment: The problem with this is that calling a function doesn't just "skip to" it -- it creates a stack frame and then, after running the function unwinds the stack, going _back_ to the old location when the function completes; and eventually, too many stack frames (if that unwinding doesn't happen) will lead to a stack overflow.