# using continue statement with while loop: bash script

Tags: linux, bash, continue

```
#! /bin/bash 

echo -e "Please enter a number: \c"
read -r x
echo -e "Please enter the last number you wished to have multiplied: \c"
read -r last_num

j=1

while [[ $j -le $last_num ]]
do
    ans=`expr $x \* $j`
    echo "$x * $j = $ans"
    ((j++))
done
echo -e "Do you wish to carry out another multiplication? [y/n] \c"
read -r response

    if [ $response == y -o $response == Y ]; then
    continue
# ***
# the continue statement does not run when I enter Y or y, but the else
# statement do run
# ***
    else
    echo "Goodbye"
    exit
    fi
```

Comment: I need help in making the loop run over again when I enter Y or y

Comment: Your code _isn't in_ the loop. Maybe you mean you want a second, larger, outer loop?

Comment: BTW, note that `expr` is an artifact of the 1970s; there's never a good reason to use it in modern code. `ans=$(( x * j ))` is both easier to read and faster to run, and guaranteed to exist in all shells compatible with the 1992 POSIX.2 standard.

Comment: And the POSIX standard for `[` doesn't guarantee that `==` will work at all, and flags `-o` as obsolescent. Better to write `if [ "$response" = y ] || [ "$response" = Y ]` or `case $response in [Yy]) continue;; esac` if you want POSIX-y code, or `if [[ $response = [yY] ]]` for bash-only code.

Comment: Anyhow -- flagged this as a duplicate of [What is the best way to go back to the beginning of a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444492/what-is-the-best-way-to-go-back-to-the-beginning-of-a-script), which is the same question you're asking.

Comment: (`continue` jumps to the next iteration of a loop, but to work, you have to use it _in a loop_)